# Debugging ruby inside a loop

Tags: ruby, debugging

I'm trying to debug a ruby application where I loop through a bunch of days and check against my employees to see whether they worked that day. The code I am working on looks like the following:

```
def search_for_worked(day)
  # debugger
  workers = employees.select do |employee|
    employee.worked?(day)
  end
  if workers.length < 1
    raise Error

end
```

I know my employee.worked? method is doing something it shouldn't be and I would like to step into it with the params that are causing the problem. However the search_for_worked method is being called ~100 times before it is getting to the day where it is failing.

I can call `catch Error` but it halts after the method so I can't step into it.

Whats the best way to debug logic errors if I only know its doing something wrong after I've already called it?

Comment: Can you post the `worked?` method?

Comment: Have you considered Pry? https://github.com/pry/pry  It will let you step into an `irb` session at your `if workers.length < 1`. You can then exit `irb` and it will pick up the program where it left off.

Comment: @Beartech yeah I wanted to use pry but inside of the employee.worked?(day) when it was messing up

Comment: Darcy, you might consider writing the body of this method as `employees.any? {|employee| employee.worked?(day)}`. That way, the method would return `true` if any employees worked; else `nil`. If you have `if(search_for_worked(day))...`, returning `nil` has the same effect as returning `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often use something like this:

```
debugger if <condition I didn't expect>
```

or

```
debugger if $foo.nil?
```

The second will be hit the first time through the loop, then I set $foo (a global) to something and continue.

Comment: Yeah ended up doing that. Except I rewrote the select block afterwards so I could step into it :/